# cant load fixtures from seeds.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I am following the Railscast#179 on how to operate with seed data

I did exactly as said in the episode and everything worked fine for me.

Now, i am trying to change fixtures directory to `spec/fixtures` instead of automatically generated `test/fixtures`

Now, when i try to create seed data from fixtures by calling

```
ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures", "langauges")
```

i am getting the following error

```
No such file or directory - /home/username/Aptana_Workspace/i18n_demo/spec/fixtures/langauges.yml
```

Do i need to change any configuration to let ActiveRecord know of my new fixtures directory ? Doesn't the path specified in the create_fixtures method is enough ?

Comment: Why change the default directory name?

Comment: i am using rspec instead of test unit, so.

Comment: Did you check to see if that file that it can't find actually exists at that path? If it doesn't where exactly (and what filename) is the file containing the fixtures you want to seed?